# Reducer Bushings for flexible liquid-tight non-metallic conduit

Tags: safety

I am building an off-grid solar system that includes components such as a PV Combiner box, all-in-one inverter, split phase transformer, main lug service panel, etc. They will all be within a few feet (no more than 4) from one another and I would like to run the cables between them inside of flexible non-metallic conduit such as this: https://www.southwire.com/wire-cable/flexible-conduit/ultratite-type-nm/p/55094401

In order to get into and out of these components, you can pickup a connector like this from any of the big box stores: https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-2-in-Non-Metallic-Liquid-Tight-Push-On-Connector-NMLT5-1/202284602

My problem is that the knockouts are varied among all the components between 1/2" and 3/4". I cannot find the appropriate non-metallic reducer bushing that connects two pieces of flexible non-metallic conduit.

Do any of you know what I should use?

Comment: You might want to run at least one metallic conduit.  It nicely wraps up all ground distribution issues.

Comment: Is your problem really that you are trying to mate two *conduits* of different sizes, or that you're trying to enlarge or reduce a *knockout* on a box to mate to a conduit + connector of a different size?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I want to connect thing A and thing B but the knockouts for thing A are 1/2" and the knockouts for thing B are 3/4". I don't understand how I can run conduit between thing A and B when their knockouts are different sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What you want is to make the knockouts match in size

Since you're in a situation where you're trying to connect a box A with a ½" KO and a box B with a ¾" KO, and are free to pick one size or the other for your conduit based on fill needs and other practical concerns, you have two options.  Either you can use a knockout (KO) punch to *enlarge* box A's KO to ¾", or use a set of *reducing washers* (of the raintight type, in your case -- if you need a part number, Bridgeport Fittings 1061-RTs will do) to to reduce box B's KO to ½".

If you don't need the extra fill of the ¾" conduit though, I'd recommend the reducing washers, as it's easier to get those right than to do KO enlargement surgery on a box.

Comment: reducing washers!  perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1" is pretty large conduit, and I suspect you are barking up one of three wrong trees.

- The conduit fill limit is based on the smallest section. You get a small credit for a section being less than 24", but you're still wasting most of 1" conduit if you step it down to 1/2".
- Use of Romex or other sheathed cable that takes up tons of space.  Don't use cable in conduit, use individual THHN or XHHW wires.  (not the unmarked wires shucked out of the cables, marked THHN/XHHW wires). Individual wires also have a higher amp rating: #8 is 50A instead of 40A; #6 is 65A instead of 55A.
- Using 1 fat conduit for *everything*.  Given your lengths (over 2') you must comply with all the conduit rules, and that will mean having to derate (up-size) larger >=45A wires when multiple circuits are in a conduit, and all wires if >4 circuits are involved.

Generally, equipment suppliers provide conduit holes that are appropriate for the wires going in/out, assuming they will be THHN in conduit, or a single cable in a cable clamp.

THHN wires are also better current-rated; #8 copper is rated 50A not 40A, and #6 copper is rated 65A not 55A (if the terminals are rated 75C thermal, not available to NM or UF cables).

### What I recommend

A dedicated conduit for any circuit 45A or over.  This works in your favor cost-wise; for instance 50A can happen with #8 copper THHN, rather than #6 copper NM.  Or for that matter, 50A can happen with #6 aluminum THHN or XHHW, for huge savings on wire cost, if the device lugs are rated for aluminum and 75C.

By the way these ampacities come out of NEC table 310.15(B)(16), with 75-90C being off-limits for 15-30A circuits, and 90C being off-limits pretty much all the time. (because precious few terminals are rated for it, terminals being the limiting factor as much as the wires).

One 1/2" conduit is fine for up to four 15-20A circuits, or up to three 30A circuits.

If able, conduits shorter than 2 feet have relaxed rules which allow sneaking more wires into them. The multi-circuit derate goes away, and the conduit fill is improved somewhat.

Anytime you're building off-grid solar stuff, you tend to be subject to criticism by inspectors, insurers and other electrical professionals.  The installation style that impresses them the most is non-flexible metal conduit (typically EMT).  I use EMT myself and find it a pleasure to work with. It handles all inter-chassis grounding *for you*.  So there's no question of whether or where to ground a metal enclosure; *it just happens*.  It's also one less wire to run; I own 10 colors of THHN wire but none are green :) As for complex bends, I don't even attempt those; I segment my bends with couplers between them. Easy mode.  You can get pre-made "offset nipples" if you only need an inch or so.

Comment: You've almost got me talked into conduit for my house addition coming this summer...

Comment: the wrong tree I am barking up is "Use of Romex or other sheathed cable that takes up tons of space. Don't use cable in conduit, use individual THHN or XHHW wires." - yes, I was planning to run nm-b romex through the conduit.